# match a pattern multiple time with a separator

Tags: c#, regex

In order to make an code cleaner i want to match multiple time my partern in a string with `;` as separator. 
For now I split on `;` like this.

```
string[] argD = _input.Split(';');
```

So the actual regex work fine. But I want to see if I can eliminate that `Split`.

#### Input:

```
1d2;1d6
```

and

```
1d2
```

#### Patern: /gmi

This pattern is giving me match for `1d2`

```regex
^(\d+)d(\d+)?$
```

For now I am splitting on `;` then I apply the regexp

#### Expected result:

```
[ [ 1 , 2 ] , [  1, 6 ] ]

[ [ 1 , 2 ] ]
```

#### MCVE: C# Code

```cs
int cpt = 0;
string uni = "1d2";
string multi = "1d2;1d8";

MatchCollection RegexMatchUni = Regex.Matches(uni, @"^(\d+)d(\d+)?$");
MatchCollection RegexMatchMulti = Regex.Matches(multi, @"^(\d+)d(\d+)?$");

Console.WriteLine("<TEST UNI>");
foreach (Match m in RegexMatchUni){
    cpt++;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}d{2}"
                        , cpt
                        , m.Groups[1].Value
                        , m.Groups[2].Value);
    var temp = m.Groups[1].Value;
}

Console.WriteLine("\n<TEST MULTI>");
cpt = 0;
foreach (Match m in RegexMatchMulti){
    cpt++;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}d{2}"
                        , cpt
                        , m.Groups[1].Value
                        , m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: Do you need to actually use a regex to "prevalidate" the input? Else, you may use a mere `String.Split`.

Comment: I have no match in `RegexMatchMulti` so that's the problem. The question is how to match this patern multiple time with a `;` separator. Excuse my English if it's not clear enought.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I and already splitting `string[] argD = _input.Split(';');` but i want to see if I can get rid of that.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `(?<^|;)(\d+)d(\d+)?(?=;|$)`.  That would match your pattern as long as it is between semicolons or the beginning and\or end of a line.

Comment: What's wrong with splitting into an array?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I have no problem with it. I just want to learn more about regex. For information the regex here is a simplified version on the actual one: `^(\d+)d(\d+)(?:\/(-?\d+))?(?:\/r(\d+))?(?:\/p(\d+))?$`, for the sake of the question.

Comment: You might try `Regex.Matches(sd, @"([0-9]+)d([0-9]+)").Cast<Match>().Select(m => new[] { m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value }).ToList();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `^` and `$` characters from your multi regexp and it will start working. These characters force the regular expression to match the entire string only, not as a substring.

Comment: I knew I was missing something really simple. *Facepalm*

Comment: @PierreLebon: No worries. We all go through that every once a week. :)